# read nodes from a file, check if they are connected

Tags: java

in an assignment I have to read a graph from a text file. the nodes are split with a "\t". the first one goes to the second(directed graph).
I do this with hashmap and arraylist(adjacency list), not sure if it's easier with adjacency matrix. but I have a problem. for example if I have

```
1   2
1   6
1   12
2   5
2   7
```

the result is : {1=[2, 6, 12, 5, 7], 2=[2, 6, 12, 5, 7]}
instead of :{1=[2, 6, 12], 2=[ 5, 7]}. i am not sure what i have to check(with the keys) to fix it.
here is a part of my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        BufferedReader inputFile = null;
        String line = new String();
        String[] par;
        int i,j;
        FileReader input = new FileReader("test.txt");
        BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(input);
        Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> graph = new HashMap<Integer , ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList <Integer> edge = new ArrayList();
        while ((line = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {

                if (line.equals("")) {
                    continue;
                }
                par = line.split("\t");
                i = Integer.parseInt(par[0]);
                j = Integer.parseInt(par[1]);
                edge.add(j);
                graph.put(i, edge);
    }
    System.out.println(graph);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
while ((line = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line.equals("")) {
            continue;
        }
        par = line.split("\t");
        i = Integer.parseInt(par[0]);
        j = Integer.parseInt(par[1]);
        if(graph.containsKey(i)){        // if for the given key , an entry exists, fetch the array and add value to it.
            edge = graph.get(i);
            edge.add(j);
            graph.put(i, edge);

        }else{                           //if there is no entry for the key, create a new list and insert values into it.
            edge = new ArrayList();
            edge.add(j);
            graph.put(i, edge);
        }

    }
```

Comment: i was trying something like this, but i wasn't creating a new list when there was no entry. thanks :) and it looks pretty obvious...i mean for each key i need a different arraylist to put the nodes in it.

do u think that i will have a prob if i work with this(and not adjacency matrixes) if i want to calculate the shortest path of the graph, the diameter and other fuctions used for graphs?

Comment: @user3029726 that really depends on specific requirements you have: for some algorithms, it's easier (and/or more time/space efficient) to use adjacency lists, for others it's easier (and/or more time/space efficient) to use an adjacency matrix etc.

Comment: i see thanks :)
one last thing if u know. To use this for the other functions/methods that i mentioned above is it the right way? i mean, i store them correct at the hash and arraylist, or there is a different(maybe better) way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are storing all the edges in the same `ArrayList` called `edge`. So basically you are loading the same value for different keys in your `HashMap graph`

What you need is something like:

```
if(graph.containsKey(i)) {
  graph.get.add(j);
}
```

Untested but should give you the gist of what is to be done. Each time before you add an edge, get the already existing list out of the graph and add the edge.

Answer (score 0):

You always `put` the same list. You need to have different lists (instances/objects) for different nodes, otherwise you will only modify the (only) existing one! e.g.

```
List<Integer> adjEdges = graph.get(i);
if(adjEdges == null)
{
   adjEdges = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
adjEdges.add(j);
graph.put(i, adjEdges);
```

Comment: oh yes u are right ,it worked and Adarsh's answer also works too.
and yea for every key(new node) i need a new arraylist to put the nodes that connect with it. looks obvious i guess :P
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make a small comparison before processing with your loop

**for instance :**

```
    int comp1;
        while ((line = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {

                        if (line.equals("")) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        par = line.split("\t");
                        i = Integer.parseInt(par[0]);
                        j = Integer.parseInt(par[1]);
                      if(comp1==null)
                     {
                     comp1=i;
                     }
              if(i!=comp1)
        {
         graph.put(i, edge);
        edge.clear()
        }

        edge.add(j);          
         comp1=i;
                }
```